# Definition of locally of finite type morphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, schemes, finitely-generated, morphism

Hartshorne defines the locally finite type morphism as follows:

**Definition:** *A morphism $f : X \to Y$ of schemes is locally of finite type if there exists a covering of $Y$ by affine open subsets $V_i = Spec B_i$, such that for each i, $f^{-1}(V_i)$ can be covered by open affine subsets $U_{ij}=SpecA_{ij}$, where each $A_{ij}$ is a finitely generated $B_i$-algebra.*

My question is: Is there something missing in this definition?

I would expect a relation between the map $B_i \to A_{ij}$ that determines the algebra structure and the map $f|_{SpecA_{ij}} : SpecA_{ij} \to SpecB_i$

Comment: The two maps you write are already the same information because $\operatorname{Spec}$ is an equivalence of categories. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: What I mean is: Given $f : X \to Y$ we can get a map $B_i \to A_{ij}$. Do we actually require this map to turn $A_{ij}$ into a finitely generated $B_i$ algebra? Or is this completely unrelated with the definition of locally of finite type morphism as stated by Hartshorne?

Comment: Yes, this map is the map which gives $A_{ij}$ the structure of a $B_i$ algebra. We require that the $B_i$-algebra structure on $A_{ij}$ given by this map make $A_{ij}$ a finitely generated $B_i$-algebra.

Comment: Thank you! This was not clear from the definition as stated by Hartshorne. I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Glad to help. I'll put the comments in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments: the $B_i$-algebra structure on $A_{ij}$ is induced via the map $f|_{\operatorname{Spec} A_{ij}} \operatorname{Spec} A_{ij} \to \operatorname{Spec} B_{i}$. This is the algebra structure Hartshorne refers to when he says that $A_{ij}$ is a finitely-generated $B_i$-algebra. (Compare to [Stack's](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01T0) definition, where the connection between the map $f$ and the algebra structure is slightly more explicit.)